# Display next or previous month in PHP with Ajax calendar

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am creating a calendar in which you can see all the reserved dates by an user. This calendar will be available to the admin but now while I am making it I have bumped into a problem, I can't seem to display the next or previous months. I need to do this with Ajax so when the admin clicks next or previous month buttons the page does not get refreshed. I have 2 buttons that respond to the ajax-jQuery `$.post` function and it works, in a way. I only can switch to one month forwards or backwards and when I go from next to prev or from prev to next the code disregards the current month and shows only those two months.

This is the index.php part code where i call for the class responsible for the calendar:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="roomss">
                <div class="calendar">
                    <div class="container-fluid header">
                        <a id="hello" href="#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:swapContent('prev')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
                        <a id="hello2" href="#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:swapContent('next')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
                        <h4 id="current_month" style="color: #fff;"><?php echo date("F, Y ",mktime(0,0,0,$month,$day,$year));?></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="availibility-calendar" class="availibility-calendar">
                        <?php
              $book = new viewBook();
              $book->showCalendar();
            ?>   
                    </div>


                </div>
      </div>
```

This is the Ajax-jQuery part:

```
function swapContent(a){
  var url = "includes/js/booking_calendar.php";
  $.post(url,{contentVar: a}, function(r){
    $("#current_month").html(r).show();
  });
  $.post(url,{contentVars: a}, function(r){
    $("#availibility-calendar").html(r).show();
  });
}
```

The `booking_calendar.php` file that swaps the content(The first isset is for changing the month title, it is quite primitive, I just add 2678400 seconds to current time):

```
<?php
include '../../../inc/config.php'; // here I include the class connection to database (private)
include '../../../inc/booking.inc.php'; // here I include class with a SELECT statement (protected)
include '../../../inc/booking-view.inc.php'; // and here I include the class which shows all the content (public)
$contentVar = $_POST['contentVar'];
if(isset($_POST['contentVar'])){
  if ($contentVar == "next") {
    $onemonth = 2678400;
    $date = time() + $onemonth;
    $curr = $date;
    $month= date("m", $curr);
    $year=date("Y", $curr);
    $day=date("d", $curr);
    echo date("F, Y ",mktime(0,0,0,$month,$day,$year));
  /*  die(var_dump($contentVar));*/
  } elseif($contentVar == "prev"){
    $onemonth = 2678400;
    $date = time() - $onemonth;
    $curr2 = $date;
    $month= date("m", $curr2);
    $year=date("Y", $curr2);
    $day=date("d", $curr2);
    echo date("F, Y ",mktime(0,0,0,$month,$day,$year));
  }
}

$contentVars = $_POST['contentVars'];
if(isset($_POST['contentVars'])){
  if ($contentVars == "next") {
    $next = new viewBook();
    $next->showNextCalendar();
  }elseif($contentVars == "prev"){
    $prev = new viewBook();
    $prev->showPrevCalendar();
  }
}
```

And this is the class function that creates the calendar it also checks from database if the dates match and highlights them red.

```
public function showCalendar(){
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Riga');
    $date = time();
    $month= date ("m", $date);
    $year=date("Y", $date);
    $day=date("d", $date);

    $first_day = mktime(0,0,0,$month, 1, $year);
    $day_of_week = date('D', $first_day);
    switch ($day_of_week) {
      case 'Mon': $blank = 0; break;
      case 'Tue': $blank = 1; break;
      case 'Wed': $blank = 2; break;
      case 'Thu': $blank = 3; break;
      case 'Fri': $blank = 4; break;
      case 'Sat': $blank = 5; break;
      case 'Sun': $blank = 6; break;

    }

    $days_in_month = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN , $month, $year);

    echo '<table class="calendar-table" border="1" >';
    echo '<tr><td style="width:60px">Mon</td><td style="width:60px">Tue</td><td style="width:60px">Wed</td><td style="width:60px">Thu</td><td style="width:60px">Fri</td><td style="width:60px">Sat</td><td style="width:60px">Sun</td></tr>';

    $day_count = 1;

    echo '<tr>';
    while ($blank > 0) {
      echo '<td></td>';
      $blank = $blank - 1;
      $day_count++;
    }

    $day_num = 1;

    while ($day_num <= $days_in_month) {
      $sql = "SELECT date_from, date_to FROM booking_2 ORDER BY book2_id";
      $result = $this->connect()->query($sql);
      $numRows = $result->num_rows;
      if($numRows > 0){
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
          $true = true;
          $date_from = $row['date_from'];
          $date_to = $row['date_to'];
          $time_from = strtotime($date_from);
          $time_fromm = idate('d', $time_from);
          $time_to = strtotime($date_to);
          $time_too = idate('d', $time_to);
        }
      }

      if ($time_fromm == $day_num) {
          for ($g = $time_fromm ; $g <= $time_too ; $g++){
            echo '<td style="border: 1px solid black; background-color:#FF3232 !important;">'.$g.'</td>';
            $day_count++;
            $day_num++;
            if ($day_count > 7) {
              echo '</tr><tr>'; 
              $day_count = 1;
            }
          }
          $day_num--;
          $day_count--;
      }else{
        echo '<td style="border: 1px solid black; background-color:#D3D3D3 !important;">'.$day_num.'</td>';
      }

        $day_num++;
        $day_count++;
        if ($day_count > 7) {
          echo '</tr><tr>';
          $day_count = 1;
        }

    }



    while($day_count > 1 && $day_count <= 7){
      echo '<td> </td>';
      $day_count++;
    }

    echo '</tr></table>';
```

and for the next and previous months there are the two different classes which are basically the same but differ from each other, in one I add 2678400 seconds `showNextCalendar();` to `time();` and in other I subtract 2678400 seconds `showPrevCalendar();` from `time();`[current month](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrgdU.png), [previous month](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKHGI.png), [next month not showing current month](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUGSz.png).

And yes I know the code displays the same dates in all months red. This is a problem I will deal with later. What I need now is a different way of creating the calendar, maybe a function that handles it all by it self, I just can't think of one. Thank you for reading this if you did! And if there are any pros out there that can help me in this matter, please do :D. Thanks again in advance.

Comment: `$onemonth = 2678400;` bad idea! Use strtotime("+1 month")  instead. If it's the 31 of january and you add those seconds you are in March.

Comment: Or yet better use `DateTime()` object. Can you try to narrow down the problem to the part which does not work.. it's TL/DR for me in monday morning.

Comment: Agree it's a bit too much text. What is the issue. I read something about you wanted a different solution? Did you try to google "php calendar"?

Comment: Of course, but all I got were paid versions, nor I need that nor I want that. Sorry for that long text, I really tried. But here is the long short version: I need to display all the months in the year by pressing the buttons, either it is next or previous month, it has to work. For me it works only one month next and one month previous. thats it.

Comment: I will change that $onemonth variable thanks.